# long delay between FiddlerBeginRequest and ServerGotRequest

Tags: silverlight-4.0, fiddler

Check the fiddler track message, we found long delay between FiddlerBeginRequest and ServerGotRequest. I was confused, cause the webserver and client is in local network.
It seems that the delay is not caused by slow network speed. Any suggestion is welcome.

ClientConnected:    14:33:25.484

ClientBeginRequest: 14:33:45.781

GotRequestHeaders:  14:33:45.781

ClientDoneRequest:  14:33:51.984

Determine Gateway:  0ms

DNS Lookup:         0ms

TCP/IP Connect: 0ms

HTTPS Handshake:    0ms

ServerConnected:    14:11:03.328

**FiddlerBeginRequest:  14:33:51.984**

**ServerGotRequest: 14:34:09.984**

ServerBeginResponse:    14:34:10.265

GotResponseHeaders: 14:34:10.265

ServerDoneResponse: 14:34:10.265

ClientBeginResponse:    14:34:10.265

ClientDoneResponse: 14:34:10.265

```
Overall Elapsed:    00:00:24.4843750
```

Comment: You asked this question over on the Fiddler discussion group, where you got a response.